# How can I encrypt my php files like asp.net does for encryption in DLLs

Tags: php, encryption

I know php is open source but I want only me to be able to open my php file, not anyone that has my code. For example when the server is hacked, it's easy for a hacker to open my php files and copy the sql username and password so it's not good for my code.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting the PHP source code to protect it from hackers is pointless because it still has to be decrypted so it can be read by the server, in order to run the code. At this point, it can be read by a hacker who has gained access.

If your server is hacked the hackers may be able to do much more than steal your database username and password. They can steal all your users' data as it comes in and out of the server. So learn to write secure code (and host on a secure host) so that you don't get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

There are free and commercial PHP `obfuscators` out there. Such as [Zend Gaurd](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) that use a certificate to encrypt the PHP files, and require Zend Optimizer to run the encrypted files. If the server is not configured with a license key for your source code the server can not run the code.

As @RobinGreen has stated. This is not going to protect you from hackers. If the hacker has access to the server they can easily copy the license as well.

It should be noted that there are many .NET decompilers out there that can reverse APS.NET DLLs back into source code. JetBrains offers a [free and full functioning decoder](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) that anyone can use easily. I'm also not aware of any ASP feature that Microsoft implemented that `encrypts` the DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is compromised, then nothing can save you. The attacker has access to the decrypting mechanism.

Your source code should be fine in the server. PHP will always be interpreted and never served as raw code.

Comment: unless you or a sysadmin misconfigures Apache!

Comment: Yes, that's true. Even Facebook messed that up.